# I am unsure how to make my dictionary print the info i want it to. Python 3.1

Tags: python, hash, dictionary

Please be gentle, I'm very new to programming and only own one book which is giving me some terrible directions (Head First Programming). Here is the code I have in the Python IDLE:

```
scores = {}

scores[8.45] = 'Zach'
scores[9.12] = 'Juan'
scores[8.31] = 'Aaron'
scores[8.05] = 'Aideen'
scores[8.65] = 'Johnny'
scores[7.81] = 'Stacey'

for key in scores.keys():
    print(scores[key] + ' had a score of ' + scores[???])
```

The program is meant to print a list containing both the names of the contestants and their corresponding scores but I dont know what I am doing wrong or right at this point :/

EDIT: Thank you guys. With your help i edited the code to working order, if you're interested here it is:

```
scores = {}

scores['Zach'] = 8.45

scores['Juan'] = 9.12

scores['Aaron'] = 8.31

scores['Aideen'] = 8.05

scores['Johnny'] = 8.65

scores['Stacey'] = 7.81

for key in scores.keys():    
    print(str(key), ' had a score of ' , scores[key])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `{...}.items()` iterator as follows:

```
for score,name in scores.items():
    print('{name} had a score of {score}'.format(**locals()))
```

However, your dictionary is in the wrong order. For example, what if Zach and Juan had the same score of 9.10? Then, writing `scores[9.10]='Zach' scores[9.10]='Juan'` would overwrite Zach! The keys should be the names.

You can write it like this:

```
scores['Zach'] = 8.45
scores['Juan'] = 8.45
...
```

---

For the record, here's how I'd do it from scratch:

```
def parseScores(string):
    scores = {}
    for line in string.splitlines():
        if line.strip():
            name,score = line.strip().split()
            scores[name] = float(score)
    return scores

data = """
    Zach 8.45
    Juan 9.12
    Aaron 2.2
    Aideen 2.2
    Johnny 2.2
    Stacey 7.81
"""

scores = parseScores(data)
for name,score in scores.items():
    print('{name} had a score of {score}'.format(**locals()))
```

Comment: OK, I replaced the bottom of my code with you're line and I instead got a complete list of the data 6 times. Although I probably did something wrong.

Comment: @gio: you should have deleted your previous for loop; the program is doing exactly what you told it to do =) "for each item, for each item, print the item"

Comment: thanks for the help, however that final code you wrote still has many parts i dont quite understand yet, but thank you for your time (:

Comment: JBernardo: It might take long if either there are many locals (however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114342/what-are-code-smells-what-is-the-best-way-to-correct-them/114352#114352 ), or if the `locals()` function is not optimized correctly. However I just tested it with a makeshift benchmark and it works reasonably speedily.

Answer (score 2):

Normally one would map players to scores, not the other way around.

```
scores = {'Zach': 8.45, 'Juan': 9.12, ...}
for player in scores:
  print('{0} had a score of {1:0.2f}'.format(player, scores[player]))
```

Comment: Sorry, your code is a bit too advanced for me. For example, I don't know how to use .format or that function within the print message.

Comment: Fortunately Python has adequate [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with regards to that.

Comment: indeed, one can even type `help(''.format)` in the interpreter